# Why is the potential energy minimal when the repulsion and attraction force between molecules is 0?

Tags: forces, potential-energy, distance

According to this potentialcurve and the other curve(?) the potential energy is minimal when the intermolecular forces equal zero.

[image]

Why? How should I interprete negative potential energy in this context?

Comment: Please provide a reference (link) for your graphs. I think they're about *inter-nuclear* energy in a molecule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that potential energy is defined up to a constant. Here it's defined so that when $r \to \infty$ the potential energy is worth 0, for convenience. So that there's nothing special about a negative potential energy per se.

What really matters here is that there's a "well", i.e. a region for $r$ where the potential energy has a minimum and that minimum is lower than for $r \to \infty$. This allows a region of stability for the molecule.

What happens is that the molecule will have discrete allowed values for its vibrational energy (an oscillator, similar to the harmonic oscillator if  the energy is small compared to the depth of the potential well), and the energy of the molecule can't be greater than the depth of the potential well in your graph, else the molecule dissociates.

More details at [this link](http://vallance.chem.ox.ac.uk/pdfs/MolecularEnergyLevelsNotes.pdf).

To answer the title question, remember that $\vec F = - \nabla \Phi$ where $\Phi$ is the potential. So that $\vec F=\vec 0$ implies $\nabla \Phi =0 \Rightarrow \frac{d \Phi}{d r}=0$, this corresponds to a minimum for $\Phi (r)$.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. I know what those mathematical operations (nabla operator = gradient, differentiation,..) mean. But I think I'll need a litlle more explanation with words and less formula's (I am not a great mathematician) to be able to understand the principle. If you don't mind?

Comment: $\vec F = - \nabla \Phi$ This means that the vorce vector equals the steepest decrease in potential in a given potential space. But why do we need the "steepest decrease"? I mean a force vector is not necessarily the most extreme one in a vectorspace. I see that  $\vec F=\vec 0$  only if the derivative of something (here $\Phi$ ) is at its minimum or maximum value. This is what I understood so far but what's the point? (I feel quite dumb for my ignorance  and asking all that stuff)

Comment: Also ou see that in the beginning Ep is at some high (maximum?) value. But the derivative, i.e. the second curve, is nowhere approaching 0.

Comment: Note that $\vec F=\vec 0$ imples that the derivative of $\Phi$ equals 0, not that it reaches a minimum or maximum. 
Basically, in words, due to the relation between the force and the potential energy, it appears that a nil force implies a local extremum (usually a local minimum if there is stability of the particle if we appart it from the equilibrium position) in the potential energy.